# gdb crashes my machine. How to debug?

Tags: linux, gdb

We're writing a fairly large system built with a collection of C++ programs. (which heavily use shared libraries)

When trying to debug any of the programs with gdb the entire machine will instantly crash and reboot if you set a break point and (I guess) the program hits the breakpoint.

I don't know where to start.  There is nothing in /var/log/messages. dmesg shows only the machine is booting again.

A monitor connected will quickly flash (I guess) a kernel panic message, and then its gone.  Can't even read what it is.  Centos 6 32 bit Distribution with:

```
# uname -a
Linux 3.16.6 #1 SMP Fri Oct 31 18:56:38 SGT 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
# gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6_4.1)
```

There doesn't seem to be any log files I can find.

What to do?  Debugging the huge system with print statements is taking forever.  Rebuild the kernel?  Any procedures or recommendations appreciated.

Comment: Be sure that you don't have hardware issues. And you probably might need more RAM. Cant you compile and run on a 64 bits x86-64 machine? BTW, you could try to compile a more recent GDB (from source) and perhaps a more recent GCC & binutils: Current GDB is 7.9, current GCC is 5.1 (april 2015)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Moving to 64bit isn't possible – huge code base with 32 bit 3rd party libraries.  The hardware shows no other problems other than crashing when GDB hits a breakpoint. I'll look into compiling a new GDB. Tons of free memory: ]# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        8066316 kB
MemFree:         5789964 kB
MemAvailable:    7815828 kB

Comment: Since  CentOS 6 comes with kernel 2.6.32, you're running your own custom kernel, correct? When did the problem with gdb start?

Comment: Yes, one of the guys built the kernel for our HW (zotac MB with i7).  GDB and breakpoints *do work*  – on smaller programs.  But hitting a breakpoint on "the big application" crashes the machine.  Including external libraries like ACE/TAO, Agent++, etc, the big app is approx. 800K lines of C++

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting a kernel panic, obviously you need to capture the output before the machine reboots. A couple of ways to do this are:

1. connect a serial line to the server, and have the console echo on serial. To do this you need to pass, say, console=ttyS0 on the kernel command line when you boot. Or alternatively,
2. use `netconsole` to send packets on the network and monitor these from another machine.

There are other options that might help too -- see here for more: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks

That said, you'll still need to fix whatever is wrong, of course. Sounds as though you're running a custom kernel -- can you take a different kernel revision (where hopefully the bug is fixed)?

Greg